# WPF combobox does not update when values change

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, mvvm, viewmodel

I have WPF application with Combobox and Button. After I enter value into textbox and press button, the value from textbox should appear in updated list of combobox. I am trying to achieve this with MVVM and binding to combobox. Here is part of code from ViewModel.

```
public class ViewModel:INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        DomainLogic dl = new DomainLogic();

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private ObservableCollection<string> expenseCategories = new ObservableCollection<string>();

        public ObservableCollection<string> ExpenseCategories
        {
            get
            {
                return expenseCategories;
            }
            set
            {
                expenseCategories = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ExpenseCategories");
            }
        }

        public ViewModel()
        {
            expenseCategories = new ObservableCollection<string>(dl.GetExpenseCategories());
        }

        private void OnPropertyChanged(string property)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
            }
        }
```

Also I am using EF to access DB and DomainLogic class has a method to list all Expense Categories.

Here is code-behind from window:

```
        DomainLogic dl = new DomainLogic();
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = new ViewModel();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox.Text))
            {
                dl.CreateNewExpenseCategory(textBox.Text);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Enter category!");
            }
        }
```

Here is also XAML:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="ExpCategory" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="72,50,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="130" ItemsSource="{Binding ExpenseCategories, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

When I add the new category the combobox isn't updated. I'm new to the whole MVVM pattern and I think I'm missing something here.

//EDIT

```
public void CreateNewExpenseCategory(string name)
        {
            using (var context = new ExpenseEntities())
            {
                ExpenseCategory category = new ExpenseCategory() { CategoryName = name};
                context.ExpenseCategory.Add(category);
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
```

Comment: any error in Output window?

Comment: @RackM no Errors

Comment: How is it (dl.CreateNewExpenseCategory(textBox.Text)) made?

Comment: @Babbillumpa Edited in question

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `CollectionChanged` event doesn't fire.

You are adding a new element inside your DataContext, but you aren't updating your local view of data.

Once you update the DataContext you should refresh your `ObservableCollection` or use Local.

Here how you could use `Local`:

```
public ViewModel()
{
      expenseCategories = dl.GetExpenseCategories().Local;
}
```

So you can directly do:

```
expenseCategories.Add(new ExpenseCategory() {textBox.Text});
dl.GetContext().SaveChanges();
```

Or you have to update the `ObservableCollection`:

```
dl.CreateNewExpenseCategory(textBox.Text);
// Update your ViewModel ObservableCollection.
```

However i think that you should use a `Command` and not an Event so you can update the `ObservableCollection` directly inside the ViewModel.

Example:

```
using Prism.Commands;
//Other usings
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
// Your class methods and properties
    public DelegateCommand<string> AddNewExpenseCategory
    {
       get
       {
            return new DelegateCommand<string>(Execute_AddNewExpenseCategory);
       }
    }

    public void Execute_AddNewExpenseCategory(string param)
    {
        expenseCategories.Add(new ExpenseCategory() { param });
        dl.GetContext().SaveChanges();
    }
```